# I can't push all my files to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to push my local repository to bitbucket, it shows me the following

```
Counting objects: 268, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (231/231), done.
Writing objects: 100% (268/268), 199.12 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 268 (delta 89), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://bitbucket.org/userName/repoName.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

when I check my files in bitbucket, not all of them are pushed, the size of my repo around 200MB and the files on bitbucket are only 250+ KB.

I tried to push again with `git push -u origin master` and `git push` and the result is:

```
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

any ideas what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Did you actually `git add` the files which are missing in Bitbucket?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, do I need to add them file by file? cuz there are hundreds of files!

Comment: You do need to add all of them, maybe the answer below will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
git update-index --really-refresh
git add .
git push
```

this will make sure that all the files are added and checked for update.

Comment: it didn't work, it shows me that everything is up to date

Comment: Run `git status` and update your question showing us what it says.  Do you have any untracked files or folders?

Comment: Can you point out any of the file that is missing in bitbucket. What I can get from your question is that you are comparing the size of your code to your local repository folder. This is totally fine as local repository contains many other objects other than actual code